# Drop down on the adaptive card feels (looks) like disabled

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am a MS Team-based bot application which sends adaptive cards into the channel, The card contains the drop down the JSON look like below:

```
{
    type: 'Input.ChoiceSet',
    id: 'statusUpdate',
    choices: actionList,
    placeholder: 'Status update',
    value: 'Select an option',
},
```

So, it feels like on the preview that the drop-down is disabled as the colour is grey, Is there a way to change the colour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no any property available to change the color of Input.ChoiceSet.

Only below properties are available for Input.ChoiceSet

type, id, choices, isMultiSelect, style, value, placeholder, wrap